# Android size package decimals (java)

Tags: java, android, size, package-managers, maxlength

i can display the size of a app package in MB but i have too much decimal numbers..

```
 ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;

        try{
            File file = new File(appInfo.sourceDir);
            double sizeInBytes = file.length();  // size in Byte
            double sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
            physicalsize.setText(""+sizeInMb);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can i have only 2 decimals like:

```
4.3 MB instead 4.35652148952
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
String.format("%.1f", sizeInMb);
```

Comment: i tryied put your code before `physicalsize.setText(""+sizeInMb);` but not works :(

Comment: You have to do it like this: physicalsize.setText(String.format("%.1f", sizeInMb));

Answer (score 0):

This should format the double into two decimal places.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
physicalsize.setText(df.format(sizeInMb))
```

James

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of:

```
double a = 123.4567;
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

The resulting output is "123.4"

You could just adapt this to your code.